# Why are there so many conflicting sources on the anatomy of Windows PE files?

Tags: executable, portable-executable

I was trying to do research on the Windows PE executable format, and every source I can find tells a different story about what sections are in a PE file.  No two sources say the same thing.  They all conflict.  I finally had to go to the Microsoft website, because I think that would be the only reliable source at this point.  Are there different versions of Windows PE or something?  What is the reason for this discrepancy?

Comment: Rather than asking people to opine on the state of web resources, why not focus on one specific issue you tried to research. Give us some context and narrowness and we might be able to help you one step closer to your research project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no 'conflicting' articles about what sections there are in a PE file. There may be a few but there most likely just plain wrong. In PE files the sections can come in different order, different names on different operating systems, etc. The whole structure of the PE file can changed just based on how the programmer programs it. The main reason that things appear so different is because there's no fixed format. Of course there are the same keywords such as PE but these can be in completely different places.

I recommend you look at PE101, it's a website that explains the PE format in great detail:

https://code.google.com/p/corkami/wiki/PE101

Also, please remove the windows-pe tag from your question. It refers to Windows PE the operating system, not the PE file format.

Comment: This is also visible in Assembly. There is no fixed format. There are keywords like section and segment and push and pop. However the format greatly depends on the Assembler (NASM, TASM, MASM, FASM, etc) and what operating system it's being programmed for (Linux, Windows, Mac OS, etc).

Comment: If your primary goal is to go lower level programming then I recommend you learn intermediate Assembly first. Then you can try programming a PE file.